# Hibernate: how to use Left Join

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hibernate-mapping, lazy-initialization

let's suppose I have two tables: TableA and TableB. TableA and TableB are in @OneToOne relation over two field (fieldA1 and fieldA2 over fieldB1 and fieldB2) and this relation could not exist for all instances of TableA.

What I would like to do with Hibernate is to have all occurrences of TableA which have or not relation with occurrences with TableB. For that, I obviously have to use left join.

Considering that TableA's Entity has a property "tableB" of TableB's Entity declared with annotation @OneToOne, how do I create the query?

Is this a correct query?

> select a from tableA a left join fetch a.tableB

My problem with this query is that when some rows of tableA doesn't have a match with any row of TableB, Hibernate throw an Exception that depends on annotations (fetch = EAGER or LAZY) I used.

I post my code to be more clear:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
public class TableA extends EvoluzioneStati implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "NUM", referencedColumnName = "NUM", insertable=false, updatable=false) })
    private TableB tableB;
other code here...
```

if I use LAZY annotation, the query processes ok but when I try to access to tableB object to check if it is null, an Exception of LazyInitialization occurs . Instead when I use EAGER annotation, it throws an Exception during processing query because some occurrences of TableA does not have a match in TableB. I precise that I can't initialize an Hibernate session when i get back the query result because of project composition and configuration.

Comment: If A references a B that does not exist, you should use the `@NotFound` annotation. Or better: fix your data.

Comment: Why should I fix data? This relation could exist for some entries of A but not for any occurrences.

Comment: Because when you have an association between two tables, there should be a foreign key constraint to ensure that there is no A referencing an unexisting B. And that's the case here, meaning that your data is in an incoherent state.

Comment: I am sorry, I disagree with that. I am not sure that a foreing key constraint implicitely requires that the foreing key value must not be null. I can have a tableA which has a field with a foreing key constraint to tableB and that field can be null, and nothing is violated. "Null" means "no value". But that's beyond the scope of the question. I asked how to manage this case with Hibernate and you give me a possible solution. Thank you for that.

Comment: The problem is not that the foreign key is null. That is perfectly fine. It means that A doesn't have a B. The problem is that the foreign key contains the identifier of a B (let's say 23), but that the table B doesn't contain any row identified by 23. That means that A is supposed to have a B, but that this this B doesn't exist.